# Javascript loop printing values to the console on the same line.. without adding the values from the previous line

Tags: javascript

This is the task:

**By a given N number, from which you need to generate a sequence of 1 to N inclusive. For every prime number in that sequence, you need to print out all the other numbers before it (and the number itself), whether they are prime or not
Example
Let's say N=10
We have the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
The prime numbers are 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 - 5 prime numbers, so we prive 5 rows
Each row contains all the numbers for 1 to PRIME_NUMBER
Result:**

```
1
12
123
12345
1234567
```

**Lets make things simpler:
Print 0 if the numbers is not prime
Print 1 if the number is prime
Final result:**

```
1
11
111
11101
1110101
```

this is my scuffed attempt:

```
let input = [
    '10',
];
 
let print = this.print || console.log;
let gets = this.gets || ((arr, index) => () => arr[index++])(input, 0);

let N = +gets();
let result;

for (let i = 1; i <= N; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)){
        printRow(i);
    }
}

function printRow(upperLimit){
    let sameLine = '';
    for(let i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            result = 1; 
        }
        if(!isPrime(i)){
            result = 0;
        }
        sameLine = sameLine + result + '';
    }
    print(sameLine);
}

function isPrime(value) {
    for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get:

```
1
111
111111
11111111101
111111111011110101
```

but I need to get:

```
1
11
111
11101
1110101
```

In my case it keeps adding what has already been looped through to the new loop on each new line. I need each new line to NOT add whatever was on the previous line.

Any help will be appreciated. Hopefully I managed to explain my problem.. it's my first question here so not sure if i am understandable with my poverty way of presenting things.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There's a `else` branch for the case you need to do something when the condition of your `if` is not fulfilled: [`if...else...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sameLine` is being declared and initialized only once, so each time printRow is called, it just adds to what was previously used. You need it to reinitialize to an empty string each time printRow is called so you just need to add `let sameLine = ''` as the first line inside `printRow` to reinitialize it each time `printRow` is invoked.

```js
function printRow(upperLimit){
    let sameLine = '';
    for(let i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            result = 1; 
        }
        if(!isPrime(i)){
            result = 0;
        }
        sameLine = sameLine + result + '';
    }
    print(sameLine);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. that fixed it.. i had let sameLine = ' '; sitting outside the function but when i moved it where you told me.. it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please replace the `if() ... if() ...` part with an `if ... else ...`. There is absolutely no reason why you want to calculate twice if the exact same number is a prime number...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isPrime(value) {
    for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function printRow(upperLimit){
    let sameLine=''
    for(let i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            result = 1; 
        }
        if(!isPrime(i)){
            result = 0;
        }
        sameLine = sameLine + result + '';
        console.log(sameLine);
    }
    
}
printRow(10)
```